# No Systems Course CS Master's

Tags: united-states, computer-science

I majored in math and minored in CS. My grades are excellent and I have coursework in all the core areas of CS except for Computer Systems/Computer Organization/Computer Architecture.

Is this going to really hurt me in admissions to (self-funded, US-based, terminal, thesis-based) MS CS programs?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you plan on focusing in systems, it shouldn't really be too much of an issue.  Especially since you are doing a self-funded MS, though I would contact the programs you are applying to just to be sure.

In some (if not all) cases, CS departments have an option for graduate students to take undergraduate courses if they are missing the background courses in certain areas (my department does this at least).  If your programs require systems courses, check to see if this is an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you do really have everything else, then I doubt that it would have much effect for most MS programs. There are probably exceptions, but, generally, admission to a MS program doesn't imply the need for a BS in the same field.

But only by applying (or otherwise asking a university) can you be sure. You may need to take a systems course as part of your MS, though. With a math degree, I doubt you'd have much trouble with it.